# Include external files in functions.php WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress I have a functions.php file containing 1500 lines of code.

Most of this code comes from a program I wrote that connects to an API and sends data from WordPress to it. I am not a WordPress developer, so I do not know if this is possible. Can you make a different file to keep functions.php clean and then include the external file inside the functions.php?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can include external files in functions.php by using either

```
require_once '<file>';
```

or else you can use

```
include_once '<file>';
```

The difference between these two is that in the event that the file is not found require will give out a fatal error and then stop executing the rest of the file where as include will only issue a warning but will continue the execution of the file.

Answer (score 20):

If you are working with a Child Theme but the path of your include route is not found:

**Try the following:**

```
include_once get_stylesheet_directory() .'/xxxx/anyfilename.php';
```

Check `get_stylesheet_directory()` to see your child theme path.

Answer (score 15):

Yes you can include the external file in functions.php

```
require_once get_template_directory() . 'anyfilename.php';
```

Comment: I know this is old but be aware this will always provide the path to the file in the *parent* theme.

Answer (score 0):

One very important suggestion:

If you want to include another PHP code into your PHP file, your included file must start with `<?php`. Ending tag is not needed.